# How to redirect from external url in webview to local app file in Android ExtendedWebViewClient (Xamarin +Javascript)?

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, webview

I am using the Android app (Xamarin + javascript), in ExtendedWebViewClient I am navigating to an external URL (Example: www.google.com) within the view. Now I need to go back to my local app files(Example: file:///android_asset/app.html) But I am getting an error saying web page is not available because when we load external URL in webview then all the local package files will not be accessible

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to achieve the resule like following GIF?

[image]

If you want to go back previous page. you can use `webView.GoBack();`

```
private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

            if (webView.CanGoBack())
            {
                webView.GoBack();
            }
        }
```

Here is my `MainActivity.cs` code

```
   [Activity(Label = "@string/app_name", Theme = "@style/AppTheme", MainLauncher = true)]
    public class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity
    {
        TextView txtURL;
        Button btnGo;
        Button btnForward;
        Button btnBack;
        WebView webView;
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            // Set our view from the "main" layout resource
            SetContentView(Resource.Layout.activity_main);
            //Get txtURL TextView, btnGo Button,webView WebView from Main Resource Layout.  
            txtURL = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.txtURL);

            btnGo = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnGo);
            btnForward = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnForward);
            btnBack = FindViewById<Button>(Resource.Id.btnBack);


            webView = FindViewById<WebView>(Resource.Id.webView1);
            webView.Settings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            //SetWebViewClient with an instance of WebViewClientClass  
            webView.SetWebViewClient(new WebViewClientClass());
            webView.LoadUrl("file:///android_asset/Content/app.html");

            //Enabled Javascript in Websettings  
            WebSettings websettings = webView.Settings;
            websettings.JavaScriptEnabled = true;

            //btnGo Click event  
            btnGo.Click += BtnGo_Click;

            btnBack.Click += BtnBack_Click;
            btnForward.Click += BtnForward_Click;
        }

        private void BtnBack_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If WebView has back History item then navigate to the last visited page.  
            if (webView.CanGoBack())
            {
                webView.GoBack();
            }
        }

        private void BtnForward_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            //If WebView has forward History item then forward to the next visited page.  
            if (webView.CanGoForward())
            {
                webView.GoForward();
            }
        }

        private void BtnGo_Click(object sender, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            var mytext=txtURL.Text;

            Toast.MakeText(this, mytext+"", ToastLength.Short).Show();
            //Load URL in txtURL in WebView.  
            webView.LoadUrl(txtURL.Text);
        }

        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Android.Content.PM.Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }



    }

    internal class WebViewClientClass : WebViewClient
    {
        //Give the host application a chance to take over the control when a new URL is about to be loaded in the current WebView.  
        public override bool ShouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, string url)
        {
            view.LoadUrl(url);
            return true;
        }
    }
```

Here is `activity_main.xml`

```
<LinearLayout  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

     <EditText  
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
            android:id="@+id/txtURL"  
             android:layout_width="match_parent"  
            android:hint="https://www.google.com"  />  
        <LinearLayout  
        android:orientation="horizontal"  
        android:layout_width="match_parent"  
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"  
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1">  

         <Button  
            android:text="Back"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            android:id="@+id/btnBack"  
            android:layout_weight="1" />  
        <Button  
            android:text="Go"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            android:id="@+id/btnGo"  
            android:layout_weight="2" />  
        <Button  
            android:text="Forward"  
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"  
            android:layout_height="match_parent"  
            android:id="@+id/btnForward"  
            android:layout_weight="1" />  
    </LinearLayout>  
    <android.webkit.WebView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" 
        android:id="@+id/webView1"/>
</LinearLayout >
```

Please do not forget to add the `INTERNET` permission in your `AndroidManifest.xml`.

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
```

Comment: @Nihal Are there any update for this issue? If the reply is helpful, please mark it as answer, it will help others who have similar issue.